# How to remove to blank option in ionic1 select

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am having a ngselect which loads data using ng-model but before selecting the data or even after selecting the data it shows an extra blank option how could i remove the blank option as well as how could i add a placeholder for the select in it.

Html:

```
<select class="formSelect" ng-model="vm.group.worker_id" ng-change="vm.fillStarted()" ng-options="worker.id as worker.name for worker in vm.selectedWorkers">
    </select>
```

[image: Select screen]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ng-seleted="value"` for that refer below link : https://codepen.io/1kohei1/pen/QjWdoz